# Clicking in UILocalNotifications when the app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm doing this app that needs to send notifications when an event is coming.

Everything is working but when the app is closed and i open through the notification it doesn't fire how it is supposed to.

My App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveLocalNotification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded()

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound |
        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))

    if let options = launchOptions {
        let value = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification
        if let notification = value {
            self.application(application, didReceiveLocalNotification: notification)
        }
    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    // Do something serious in a real app.
    println("Received Local Notification:")
    println(notification.alertBody)


    if notification.alertAction == "editList" {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil);
    }


}
```

In my main tab controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleModifyListNotification", name: "modifyListNotification", object: nil)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.repaint()
}


func handleModifyListNotification(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Show the alert
    })

}
```

The main objective is when a notification is pressed with the app closed, it opens, executes didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and checks for UILocalNotification in launchOptions and calls didReceiveLocalNotification.

ps: i know with debug that the notifications is being well received, the system is just not calling the didReceiveLocalNotification method, like it should.

**1º Edit**

I'm really calling the didReceiveLocalNotifaction method because i just tried this and it worked

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    // Do something serious in a real app.
    println("Received Local Notification:")
    println(notification.alertBody)



    if notification.alertAction == "editList" {

        var xpto = UIAlertView()
        xpto.title = notification.alertAction!
        xpto.show() NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil);
    }


}
```

So i gess this must be a timing issue. I really want my tab controller to react to this notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, -didReceiveLocalNotification: is only called when the app is in active state and being used.

If you're attempting to launch the app from a background state, I would suggest using -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and querying your options.

For this reason, maybe have your notification handling code in a separate method and have it called from both -didReceiveLocalNotification & -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: Please read my last edit. The final thing to be resolved is NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil);. This should trigger the observer in my tab controller...

Comment: Have you considered performing the notification after a time delay (to ensure the app is launched from background completely) ? I'm not fully up to speed with swift, but in objective-c, it would be something on the lines of [self performSelector:@selector(methodToTriggerTabControllerObserver) afterDelay:1.0]

Comment: var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("someSelector"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
        
        func someSelector() {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil);
        }

Comment: Happy to help! Can you please mark this question as answered?